# ElasticSearch NEST Delete all document

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using ElastciSearch 2.3.0

I am trying to delete documents from the ElasticSearch using .net and NEST for specific index.

I only want to delete all documents and not the _mapping

```
DeleteByQueryRequest r = new DeleteByQueryRequest(new IndexName() { Name = indexName });
r.QueryOnQueryString = "*";                            
var response = client.DeleteByQuery(r);
```

I am try to do this by using above code but it is not working.

Please suggest on what's wrong with the above code or how this can be done.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Which version of Elasticsearch are you running?

Comment: I would recommend to copy the mapping to a new index and delete the existing index. Deleting _all_ documents in an index to preserve the mapping is a very expensive operation!

Comment: I am using 2.3.0 version of elasticsearch

Answer (score 3):

Don't use delete by query it was made a plugin since elastic 2.0 for a good reason. You can get out of memory exceptions easy.
You should delete the whole index and recreate the mappings

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ElasticClient db = new ElasticClient(new Uri("http://localhost.fiddler:9200"));

            db.IndexMany(Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(i => new Data { Id = i, Name = "Name" + i }), "test_index");

            var mappings = db.GetMapping<Data>();

            var delete = db.DeleteIndex(new DeleteIndexRequest("test_index"));

            var indexMapping = mappings.IndexTypeMappings["test_index"].ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => (ITypeMapping)v.Value);

            db.CreateIndex(new CreateIndexRequest("test_index")
            {
                Mappings = new Mappings(indexMapping)
            });

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        class Data 
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

Raw copy of index

```
var res = db.LowLevel.IndicesGetMapping<JObject>("test_index"); 
var delete = db.DeleteIndex(new DeleteIndexRequest("test_index"));
var mappings = res.Body["test_index"].ToString(); 
var create = db.LowLevel.IndicesCreate<JObject>("test_index", mappings);
```

If you really need to install the plug-in
sudo bin/plugin install delete-by-query

Comment: Hi Filip, Thanks a lot for this. I have one more problem. In my case I don't have any class like "Data". And when I try to run code at client.GetMapping I get error. 'var MappingRequest = new GetMappingRequest(indexToCreate);
var map = client.GetMapping(MappingRequest);'

Comment: No problem just use db.GetMapping(new GetMappingRequest(new Nest.IndexName() { Name = "test_index" }) { });

Comment: This is giving the below error.  '# FailureReason: Unrecoverable/Unexpected BadResponse while attempting GET http://localhost:9200/contact/_mapping
 - [1] BadResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Exception: JsonSerializationException Took: 00:00:00.3850932
# Audit exception in step 1 BadResponse:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "analyzed" to type 'System.Nullable`1[Nest.NonStringIndexOption]'. Path 'index', line 1, position 128. ---> System.ArgumentException: Requested value 'analyzed' was not found.'

Comment: Do you get the Mappings before the deletion?

Comment: try this  `var res = db.LowLevel.IndicesGetMapping<JObject>("test_index");
           var delete = db.DeleteIndex(new DeleteIndexRequest("test_index"));
           var mappings = res.Body["test_index"].ToString();
           var create = db.LowLevel.IndicesCreate<JObject>("test_index", mappings);`

Answer (score 0):

It worked.
Thanks a lot.

```
var res = db.LowLevel.IndicesGetMapping<JObject>("test_index"); 
var delete = db.DeleteIndex(new DeleteIndexRequest("test_index")); 
var mappings = res.Body["test_index"].ToString(); 
var create = db.LowLevel.IndicesCreate<JObject>("test_index", mappings);
```

Comment: If it helped, please upvote their answer and if it provided the solution to the problem, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!